# add main menu item in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I have many content type that I have added in drupal 7 and I want them to be available in main menu. For example I have content types:

- news
- events

and I want the main menu look like

> home - news - events

Despite I checked available `menu > main menu`
it doesn't show up in the main menu. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content types refer to the different types of nodes that you can create.  Making your news content type available for the main menu means that, when you create news nodes, you can place them in that menu.

If you are trying to create a page that lists news nodes, you need to look into the Views module.  It will allow you to create pages or blocks containing lists of content.  Then, you can put those pages in the main menu.  You can find the Views module here: http://drupal.org/project/views

Comment: yes i know this way for sure
but i thought there would be direct way when u create
a content type to put it in main menu.
thanks any way pjskeptic.

Comment: What do you mean by putting the content type in the menu?  What would you want the News and Events links to link to?

Comment: like if i made content type (articles)
then in the content type options there should be url like (articles)
then put this link in the main menu

Comment: I think you are confusing content types with nodes.  Content types describe the fields that nodes have.  When you go create a News or Event node you'll be presented with menu options and the ability to specify a url.